# Formato tabla con libreria TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Estoy intentando dar formato a una tabla generada mediante una consulta a mysql a través de la librería TCPDF.

En esta parte del código genero la tabla, pero las condiciones colspan, rowspan o  width no las tiene en cuenta al dibujar la tabla.

```
    function generateRow(){
    $idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
    $contents = '';
    $content = '';
    include_once('connection.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM direccionescarga WHERE idviaje='$idviaje'";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $content .= "
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>Remitente:".$row['nombredircar']."</td>
            <td colspan='3'>Dirección:".$row['direcciondircar']."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Cod.Pos.".$row['codigopostaldircar']."</th>
            <th colspan='2'>Población".$row['poblaciondircar']."</th>
            <th>".$row['provinciadircar']."</th>
            <th>".$row['paisdircar']."</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>".$row['fechacar']."</th>
            <th>".$row['horariocar']."</th>
            <th>".$row['referenciacar']."</th>
            <th>".$row['contactocar']."</th>
            <th>".$row['telefonocar']."</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='5'>".$row['observacionesdircar']."</td>

        </tr>
        ";
    }
    $contents=$content;


    return $contents;
}
```

Esta es el resultado de la tabla una vez dibujada en pdf.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os dejo el código completo.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda

```
        <?php

    $idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
    $username=$_REQUEST['username'];




        require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
        // Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
    class MYPDF extends TCPDF {



        // Page footer
        public function Footer() {
            // Position at 15 mm from bottom
            $this->SetY(-15);
            // Set font
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
            // Page number
            $this->Cell(0, 10, '´Página '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        }
    }  
        $pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
        $pdf->SetTitle("Generated PDF using TCPDF");  
        $pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
        $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
        $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
        $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
        $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
        $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
        $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
        $pdf->setPrintFooter(true);  
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11);  
        $pdf->AddPage();  

        $tbl = <<<EOD
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/logo_example.jpg" alt="test alt attribute" width="155" height="92" border="0"></td>
            <td><p sice="20"></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>


            </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


            <td><img src="images/logo_transnet.png" alt="test alt attribute" width="118" height="57" border="0" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    EOD;

    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');

    $tbl2 = <<<EOD
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Para:$idviaje</td>
            <td>De:$nombreuser</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    EOD;

    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl2, true, false, false, false, '');

        function generateRow(){
            $idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
            $contents = '';
            $content = '';
            include_once('connection.php');

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM direccionescarga WHERE idviaje='$idviaje'";
            $query = $conn->query($sql);
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                $content .= "
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>Remitente:".$row['nombredircar']."</td>
                    <td colspan='3'>Dirección:".$row['direcciondircar']."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cod.Pos.".$row['codigopostaldircar']."</th>
                    <th colspan='2'>Población".$row['poblaciondircar']."</th>
                    <th>".$row['provinciadircar']."</th>
                    <th>".$row['paisdircar']."</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>".$row['fechacar']."</th>
                    <th>".$row['horariocar']."</th>
                    <th>".$row['referenciacar']."</th>
                    <th>".$row['contactocar']."</th>
                    <th>".$row['telefonocar']."</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='5'>".$row['observacionesdircar']."</td>

                </tr>
                ";
            }
            $contents=$content;


            return $contents;
        }

        $content = '';  
        $content .= '

            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">  
               <tr>  
                    <th width="100%" colspan="5">DIRECCIÓN DE CARGA</th>

               </tr>  
          ';  
        $content .= generateRow();  
        $content .= '</table>';  
        $pdf->writeHTML($content); 





        $pdf->Output('members.pdf', 'I');


    ?>
```

Comment: aqui tienes un ejemplo claro donde lo usan : https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_048/

Comment: @Tegito123 En este ejemplo las tablas son estáticas. Si te fijas en el código completo tengo tablas tomadas de ese ejemplo que indicas. El problema me surge al intentar crear las tablas dinámicamente. No he encontrado ningún ejemplo en la documentación de la librería que  lo trate. Gracias por contestar

Comment: checa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548225/how-to-create-tcpdf-html-table-with-variable-row-paddings

Comment: @Tegito123 Gracias por tu tiempo, pero sigue sin tomar en cuenta cualquier condición que añado dentro de la tabla que se genera dinámicamente. Podría parchear como indica ese ejemplo y crear una tabla para cada fila, pero seguiría sin poder modificar el ancho de las columnas ni podría añadir color de fondo o cualquier otra condición que necesitara.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución, hay que escribir entre doble comilla los atributos , con la camilla simple no los tiene en cuenta.

El código para la tabla queda de la siguiente manera:

```
    function generateRow(){
            $idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
            $contents = '';
            $content = '';
            include_once('connection.php');

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM direccionescarga WHERE idviaje='$idviaje'";
            $query = $conn->query($sql);
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                $content .= '
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Remitente:'.$row['nombredircar'].'</td>
                    <td colspan="3">Dirección:'.$row['direcciondircar'].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cod.Pos.'.$row['codigopostaldircar'].'</th>
                    <th>Población'.$row['poblaciondircar'].'</th>
                    <th>'.$row['provinciadircar'].'</th>
                    <th>'.$row['paisdircar'].'</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>'.$row['fechacar'].'</th>
                    <th>'.$row['horariocar'].'</th>
                    <th>'.$row['referenciacar'].'</th>
                    <th>'.$row['contactocar'].'</th>
                    <th>'.$row['telefonocar'].'</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">'.$row['observacionesdircar'].'</td>

                </tr>

                ';
            }
```